# How can I implement large product photos without affecting the layout of my theme?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, rwd

I want to add large product photos to my store. At the Momemt I can add like 600x 400 images to my score without affecting the layout of my product page. However If I change the width to let's say 1200 pixel, the product options will appear under the photos instead beside them. What can I do?